# Change Headers for Certain Columns in CSV File

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file that I want to change the headers only for certain columns (about 20 of them in my actual file). Here's a sample CSV file:

**CSV File**

```
"name","blah_01_blah","foo_1_01_foo","bacon_01_bacon","bacon_02_bacon"
"John","yucky","summer","yum","food"
"Mary","","","cool","sundae"
```

I have been trying this with a File/IO class, but when it reads the file to do the `gsub` it removes all of the quotation marks around each string separated by commas. Here's the code I'm using:

**Ruby Code**

```
file = 'file.csv'

replacements = {
    'blah_01_blah' => 'newblah1',
    'foo_01_foo' => 'coolfoo1',
    'bacon_01_bacon' => 'goodpig1',
    'bacon_01_bacon' => 'goodpig2'
}

matcher = /#{replacements.keys.join('|')}/

outdata = File.read(file).gsub(matcher, replacements)

File.open(file, 'w') do |out|
out << outdata
end
```

What I end up with is this in the CSV file:

**New CSV File**

```
name,blah_01_blah,foo_1_01_foo,bacon_01_bacon,bacon_02_bacon
John,yucky,summer,yum,food
Mary,"","",cool,sundae
```

It's keeping the quotation marks in fields that are blank, but taking them out around the strings elsewhere. I want to retain those quotation marks in case for some reason a rogue comma ends up in a string somewhere so it doesn't get thrown off. How can I change the headers without losing my quotation marks around the strings?

**EDIT - This is what I want the file to look like at the end.**

**Expected Result CSV File**

```
"name","newblah1","coolfoo1","goodpig1","goodpig2"
"John","yucky","summer","yum","food"
"Mary","","","cool","sundae"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you reading the *whole file* (`File.read(file)`) when you only want to edit the *headers* (first line)? That's very inefficient, and potentially error prone.

Comment: What do you _want_ the CV to look like at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to handle CSV at all:

```
File.write(
  file,
  File.readlines(file).tap do |lines|
    lines.first.gsub!(matcher, replacements)
  end.join
)
```

[`File#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readlines).

The trick here is we actually deal with the first line only, as with plain text.

Comment: Ok, getting closer. Your answer worked to change the headers, but now I have a blank row added in between each of the existing rows for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create the input CSV file.

```
text =<<_
"name","blah_01_blah","foo_1_01_foo","bacon_01_bacon","bacon_02_bacon"
"John","yucky","summer","yum","food"
"Mary","","","cool","sundae"
_

file_in  = 'file_in.csv'
file_out = 'file_out.csv'
File.write(file_in, text)
  #=> 137
```

Here is the `replacements` hash, which I simplified slightly.

```
replacements = {'blah_01_blah'=>'newblah1', 'foo_01_foo'=>'coolfoo1',
                'bacon_01_bacon'=>'goodpig1'}
```

The first task is to modify this hash so that if it has no key `k`, `replacements[k]` will return `k`. For this we use the method [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).

```
replacements.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }
```

Here are two examples of how this hash is used.

```
replacements['bacon_01_bacon']
  #=> "goodpig1"
replacements['name']
  #=> "name"`
```

The latter follows because `replacements` has no key `'name'`.

The code is as follows.

```
require 'csv'

f_in = CSV.read(file_in, headers:true)
CSV.open(file_out, 'w') do |csv_out|
  csv_out << replacements.values_at(*f_in.headers)
  f_in.each { |row| csv_out << row }
end
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

Note that

```
f_in.headers
  #=> ["name", "blah_01_blah", "foo_1_01_foo", "bacon_01_bacon", "bacon_02_bacon"]
```

Let's look at the output file.

```
puts File.read(file_out)
```

prints

```
name,newblah1,foo_1_01_foo,goodpig1,bacon_02_bacon
John,yucky,summer,yum,food
Mary,"","",cool,sundae
```